# rsnapshot Freezes when Backing up to NFS Mount

Tags: nfs, rsync, rsnapshot

I've got a Server running Ubuntu Server 14.04 server that has been doing periodic back-ups to an NFS mounted NAS using rsnapshot for several months now without issue.  Last week we added a few more machines to the switch and we started having issues with the back-up and NFS mount.

Rsnapshot will run it's rsync command, which will run fine for an hour or two before it just seems to stop doing anything.  The rsync command will show up in `top` as being in an 'uninterruptable sleep' state (`31948 root 25 5 79640 56328 452 D 0.0 0.1 15:13.86 /usr/bin/rsync -a --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/etc/rsnapshot.excludefile /home /mnt/.private/backup/daily.0/localhost/`).

Once this happens, I can't look at the NFS mount any more.  If I try to ls the directory, the ls command will just freeze, and the load on the server will go through the roof unless I find the PID for that ls command and kill it.

After it's gotten to this stage, the only way I can get back on the NFS mount is if I physically reboot the NAS box.

Any ideas?  Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem.  It turns out that adding new machines to the switch had nothing to do with it.  The same day that we added those machines, one of the users created a single huge file (~260GB).  NFS was stalling out copying that file.  My solution was to add `--max-size=100G` to the rsync command in rsnapshot.  This means that one large file isn't getting backed up, but I'm accepting that for now since it's better to miss one file that might affect one user than to have the whole back-up fail.